# XSLT apply templates to subsets

Tags: xslt

I have this situation:

```
<root>
 //first block other tags

 <data>something</data> //first
 <data>something</data>
 <data>something</data>
 ...others <data/>
 <data>something</data> //last

 //follows second block other tags
</root>
```

I need to apply-templates to all the tags before the first `<data/>` and apply-templates to all the other tags following last `<data/>`.

Have you any idea how to select this subsets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select all elements before the first data element, do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="data[1]/preceding-sibling::*" />
```

To select all elements after the last data element, do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="data[last()]/following-sibling::*" />
```

Or, do select them both at the same time....

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="data[1]/preceding-sibling::*|data[last()]/following-sibling::*" />
```

This assumes you are positioned on the **root** element, and that there is at least one **data** element present though.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to apply-templates to all the tags before the first `<data/>` and
>   apply-templates to all the other tags following last `<data/>`.

**As it seems from the provided XML document, there are no non-`data` elements between the first and last `data` elements, therefore use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::data)]"/>
```